# Intel Graphics HD on Windows 8 RTM on a Dell Latitude E6410

Tags: drivers, virtual-machine, dell-latitude, windows-8

Just wondering if anyone has installed Windows 8 RTM on a dell Latitude 6410 with the Intel HD Graphics (or whatever the integrated video card exact name is).

I tried getting the latest drivers from intel, but apparently they are only for the Release Preview, so the install won't go through saying the computer does not meet the minimum requirements.

I couldnt find a more up to date driver, and the thing is I'm installing this on a VM, and I just can't get the ideal resolution for this laptop (which is 1440 x 900).

has anyone done it, or has any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FYI, an official driver was released in Ocotober and can be found int download center http://downloadcenter.intel.com/ . In my case this worked out of the box via Windows Update.

Comment: thanks Misha. I actually had this issue back when I installed Windows 8 on a VM. I actually upgraded my machine last week to Windows 8 and it picked up that update automatically.